# Transform an inertia tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

I am trying to provide colleagues with a spreadsheet method of transforming the inertia properties of a complex shaped body to a different coordinate system, involving only rotation.

I've read that this can be achieved by multiplying the inertia tensor by the transform of the matrix of direction cosines and then multiplying the matrix of direction cosines by the previous result:

$$[I'] = [T][I][T]^T$$

The body in question has been drawn in CAD so that the principal axes and inertias, and the inertia relative to a global axis system, can be obtained. In addition I created a second global coordinate system with a common origin to the original system and with a simple rotation about a single axis. This gives me a further set of values relative to this second global coordinate system. I then put all the numbers into Excel expecting to use the above matrix maths to transform one of the inertia tensors into any of the others using the appropriate direction cosines. Unfortunately, that isn't working, so I assume I am misunderstanding something.

As an example:

T (the direction cosines for the principal axes) =

(0.32819818 -0.0000209) (0.94460889

-0.00012885 -0.99999999) (0.00002264)

(0.94460888 -0.00012914 -0.32819818)

$T^T$ (i.e. the inverse) using MINVERSE(Array) =

(0.32819818 -0.000128846) (0.944608882

-2.09024E-05 -0.999999993 -0.000129143)

(0.944608889 2.26412E-05 -0.32819818)

I (the principal inertias) =

$148478195.6 0 0$

$0 271583441.8 0$

$0 0 281696001$

So, finding $[I][T]^T$ using MMult(Array1,Array2) =

(48730273.62 -19130.84153) (140253822.4

-5676.743151 -271583439.8 -35073.17172)

(266092546.6 6377.931954 -92452114.86)

Then finding $[T]([I][T]^T)$ =

(267346572.3 5422.037743 -41300039.62)

(5422.182592 271583439.7) (14908.35047

-41300039.57) (14907.89697) (162827626.4)

The CAD gives the inertia relative to the global system as:

(267346571.9) (389.2392844) (41300040.2)

(389.2392844) (271583441.9 -2858.85771)

(41300040.2 -2858.85771) (162827624.7)

The diagonal terms are pretty well correct, but the others are not. The second example using a simple rotation about a single axis also produced incorrect results, although this time only two of the three products were correct and none of the moments. I won't post that here unless requested.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please format any mathematical content using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and check out our [advice on what is on-topic here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Many people would regard this as a "check-my-work" type of question, and therefore off-topic. So I'm only prepared to make a comment or two.

Comment: This is the transformation $\quad\,I_T=R^T\,I\,R\quad$ where $R$ is the orthonormal rotational matrix

Comment: Have you thought about what happens if you interchange $T$ and its transpose? This will get you closer to the numbers in your CAD answer. You might need to read about conventions for rotations (such as active vs passive). If you see some sign discrepancies, maybe these correspond to some of the direction cosine vectors having their signs switched somehow. There might be an issue with the definition of right-handed and left-handed coordinate systems. These are just thing to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and corrections. I will take some time to study the problem further. In the meantime, can you tell me why the direction cosines have been bracketed the way they have? They aren't in triplets anymore.

Answer (score 2):

See Goldstein, Classical Mechanics, for the details supporting this answer.

The two coordinate systems need to be orthogonal (Cartesian).  The nine direction cosines are not independent for a transformation matrix between orthogonal coordinate systems.  Check to see that your direction cosines form an orthogonal transformation.  Also, for motion of a rigid body, the determinant of the transformation matrix must have value +1.  Check that the determinant for your transformation matrix has value +1.

These requirements for the transformation can be accounted for using the three Euler angles for the transformation matrix.  An example application of the Euler angles is discussed in [Rigid Body Motion and defining $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{\omega}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/618143/rigid-body-motion-and-defining-vecl-and-vec-omega). This example includes transformations of the inertia tensor between body and inertial (space) coordinates.